# how to manage processes in C language with daemon-process

Tags: c, ubuntu, process, signals, daemon

I made an app-process in C language, but I want to manage the app process by creating a daemon process. (If app-process die, rerun, etc.)

I'm trying to do it, but please help me with how to manage it.

Usually, do you process it with a signal in the field or do you process it with a pid value?

Please help me

Comment: Usually processes which must be monitored and restarted if terminated are managed by systemd. Create systemd service.

Comment: You have to handle `SIGINT` and `SIGTERM` for graceful shutdown your program. Other than that just let `systemd` manage your daemon as it like.